# Подсветить строку и столбец в таблице с полосатой разметкой, сохранив границы ячеек

Tags: html, css, css3

**Без javascript'а** надо подсветить строку и столбец в таблице с полосатой разметкой, сохранив границы ячеек.

Что есть (Chrome):
[image]
HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table__row table__row_header">
            <th class="table__cell table__cell_header">title 1</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="table__row table__row_body">
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <span class="table__content">text 11</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <span class="table__content">text 12</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <div class="table__content">text 13</div>
            </td>
            <td class="table__cell table__cell_body">
                <div class="table__content">text 14</div>
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: default;
}
    .table__row {
        position: relative;
    }
        .table__row_body:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }
        .table__row_body:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    .table__cell {
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 10px solid cadetblue;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
        .table__cell_header {
            z-index: 20;
            background-color: darkslategrey;
            color: white;
        }
        .table__cell_body:hover:after {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            top: -5000px;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10000px;
            content: "";
            background-color: lightyellow;
        }
        .table__row_body:hover .table__cell_body {
            background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        }
    .table__content {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
    }
```

Что хочется получить:
[image]

[Исходный код](http://jsfiddle.net/wnfh1acx/)

Comment: В IE11 границы есть как на картинке, а вот в FF39 их вообще не наблюдается. Я про нижний скрин.

Comment: подтверждаю, в ФФ выглядит так https://www.dropbox.com/s/9d3oicbcnhz02b5/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202015-08-01%2016.34.25.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение в том, чтобы использовать в подсветке цвет, близкий к цвету границы, и сделать ее более прозрачной:

```
background-color: rgba(95,158,160,.5);
```

вместо

```
background-color: lightyellow;
background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
```

[Результат](http://jsfiddle.net/wnfh1acx/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать **background-image**, и репитнуть его по **Y** вместо **background-color: lightyellow;** для  **.table__cell_body:hover:after**. Но тогда будет фиксированная высота ячейки.